# Visual Studio 2013 C++ - How to determine which line write to my variable?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

today I encountered weird problem, one of my global variables somehow gets corrupted.
I tried modifying it during runtime (assigned some key for it), while I'm holding button it is ok, but as soon as release it less significant byte is zeroed (corupted). In fact its dancing around this two values, I am using Cheat Engine to check value.

I checked all references to it, and for sure I can say I only write to it on program start, later only read from it. So most likely its some bad pointer, overflow, or something.

I attached Cheat Engine's debbuger and easily found which assembly code write to it (I can see exact names of function calls around) and that way tried to determine which line is bad, but when watching code there is no command between these two function calls.
I already use safe functions in my code (strcpy_s, ...), and aswell always sizeof macro, not sure where could things go wrong.

Is there a way in Visual Studio to determine which line write to my variable (address)? Or any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use Visual Studio's debugger and set a watch on it... *safe functions in my code (strcpy_s* You can still use these functions wrong.

Comment: I cannot find any good (clear) references on how to use watch. Can You provide any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll be trashing memory - something will be writing to memory in the block before your variable, but "overflowing" into the memory location your variable lives in. What I'd do is put a memory breakpoint on (check the VC docs if you can't figure it out from the breakpoint menu) and wait for it to change. Then you can see in the call stack which routines are being processed, which should some memory update (eg a C-style string clear or a memset or similar).

Comment: After a bit more testing I'd say my problem is not at all about writing to unwanted block of memory. I tried commenting same _beginthread() and found out when I comment some specific ones that problem is solved. Ofcourse for proper program running I need this threads. Was playing with it a bit more and I put return; on each thread start, so that it exit right as it starts, bug is still there. Same as if I just comment all lines in this functions. Could it be problem because of high thread count of program? It is running about 40 threads.

Comment: It turns out to be my fault...
Variables were just differently stored in memory in case I would comment something. Probably I corrupted something else then.